# find: bad option -printf find: path-list predicate-list shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I've just made a very basic shell script which takes a input path and displays the attributes of the files in that path.

Problem: the script is running on my PC, but when I try to run it on my college UNIX server I'm getting an error:

```
find: bad option -printf
             find: path-list predicate-list
```

- My PC: Ubuntu
- My college server: SunOS nyx 5.9 Generic_118558-11 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " enter address in form : /home/rohan/../.."
read ARG

if [ -n "$ARG" ]; then
echo "input path taken : $ARG"    
# ls -lsh $ARG"/"*.txt 

else
     ARG=$(pwd)
fi

echo " enter option "
echo " 1. file size, 2. permission, 3. owner/group, 4. all , 5. exit" 
read OPTION

while [ $OPTION != "5" ]
do


  if [ $OPTION = "1" ]; then
  find $ARG"/"*.txt  -printf " %p     %s bytes   \n"


 elif [ $OPTION = "2" ]; then
 find $ARG"/"*.txt  -printf " %p     %M    \n" 


 elif [ $OPTION = "3" ]; then 
 find $ARG"/"*.txt  -printf " %p     %g    \n" 

 elif [ $OPTION = "4" ]; then 
 find $ARG"/"*.txt  -printf "%p      %s bytes    %M     %g    \n"

   fi

  echo "enter option again"
  echo " 1. file size, 2. permission, 3. owner/group, 4. all , 5. exit" 
  read OPTION
 done
```

Comment: Older find version on Sun doesn't support `-printf` option

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can implement it in another way ?

Comment: Try `find /opt/sfw -name find -print` to see if the admins installed the GNU find there.

Comment: It could also be in /usr/sfw or /usr/local/bin, blastware.com and its successor optcsw.com let you determine where to install.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems on Solaris -printf and your general syntax,

try:

```
find $ARGS -name '*.txt' -exec ls -l {} \; | nawk '{print $5, $(NR) }'
```

Where ARGS is a directory not a filename.  Use -name.  Next printf - you will have to use something like what I gave you - pipe ls -l for each file into nawk - NOT awk on Solaris - and print the fields you want. bytes are field #5, so `'{print $5}'`  works for that.  the last field `$(NR)` is the filename

awk on solaris is a very very old implementation and you cannot port unbuntu GNU awk syntax and generally have it work the way you want on solaris awk.

Comment: You should leave `find $ARG"/"*.txt` which is actually correct and might provide a different output than `find $ARGS -name '*.txt'`

Comment: Except that on Solaris 10 find interprets it as a directory, not a .txt file.  So while it may be legal syntactically, based on his results with ls it looks like the OP wants -name '*.txt' or some similar variant.

Comment: Solaris `find` doesn't demand the path argument(s) to be directories. It definitely accepts a list of files here which is what the initial command is sending (unless there are directories with dubious `.txt` suffixes). If the OP wants for `.txt` files located in sub-directories to be reported, your reply is correct but there is no evidence he wants that (or not ...)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `find -printf` is to use `stat --printf` on a set of files to print useful info about them. This is a code snippet that factors out calls to `find` and uses shell glob to match the set of files:

```
# ...


usage() {
   echo "enter option again"
   # ...
}

# read options
while read OPTION; do
    format=""
    case $OPTION in
        1) format="%n    %s bytes\n" ;;
        2) format="%n    %A\n" ;;
        3) format="%n    %U/%G\n" ;;
        4) format="%n    %s bytes  %A  %U/%G\n" ;;
        5) exit ;;
        *) usage ;;
    esac

    # print file info 
    shopt -s nullglob
    for file in "$ARG"/*.txt; do
        stat --printf "$format" "$file"
    done
done
```

Comment: Solaris 9 did NOT ship with stat.  It may or may not be there.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Hmmm, there seems to be a package [coreutils](http://unixpackages.com/package-list-sparcsolaris-9?frm_search=coreutil) for the Solaris SPARC 9 system. Not sure if it contains `stat` though.

Comment: http://www.opencsw.org/use-it/sharing-optcsw/  this does have a findutils package.  If you want one.  stat is buried somewhere else in there.  sunfreeware also has GNU coreutils which has find.  But the site is now locked down.